# How to create session database using express-mysql-session and mysql2?

Tags: express-session, mysql2

I am using Node version 18.12.0 and MYSQL Workbench for my database

My node server crashes when i run the following code

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const session = require("express-session");
    require("dotenv").config();
    const mysql = require("mysql2");

    // Package documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session
    const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);

    // Create the Express application
    var app = express();

    // Connection to database is already set in the config folder
    const options = {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      user: process.env.USER,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    };

    const conn = mysql.createConnection(options);

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({
      expiration: 10000000,
      createDatabaseTable: true,
      schema: {
        tableName: "sessiontbl",
        columnNames: {
          session_id: "session_id",
          expires: "expires",
          data: "data",
        },
      },
    conn //<== issue here
    });

    app.use(
      session({
        key: "keyin",
        secret: "some secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // Equals 1 day ( 1 day * 24 hr/1 day * 60 min/1 hr )
        },
      })
    );

    app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
      res.send("<h1>Hello World (Sessions)</h1>");
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

This is what it outputs
[image: The error output]

I am trying to create a session database with express session and mysql2.

It does create the table in the database but the server crashes .. i have tried mysql2/promise and pool methods but i am not sure where to use the async await in this scenario. The issue happens in the sessionStore variable.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom database table schema, you have to set the createDatabaseTable option to FALSE.

This article can help:

https://darifnemma.medium.com/how-to-store-session-in-mysql-database-using-express-mysql-session-ae2f67ef833e